Modifyng a deformed object so it has the same shape as the original
I have two png of the same object. However, png_b has the object a bit deformed, as if it was squished. Both of the images don't have the same shape or the same ratio.
I'm coding in python and need to find a way to modify png_b so it has the same shape as png_a (the object needs to have the same shape in both pictures). I'm trying to use SimpleITK, but I can't get it to work.
The process needs to be automatic, I can't do it manually.
Any help is highly appreciated.
I tried using ORB, edge detection (the images were both put in binary) and SSIM to find similarities between images before modifying them and failed to detect enough similarities modify it.
I then tried using SimpleITK, but I'm fairly new to it and don't quite understand how it works.

sorry to be the one to tell you this is not that simple to do. EVEN after you paste some skeleton code to at least have both images as Python objects in a code snippet you control, and can pass then to functions.
As it is now, with no code, or image examples at all, there are no elements even to keep the question open.

Please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
